# CodeIgniter Active Record includes columns from previous query

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a function that needs to run 2 queries.  The first query runs fine.  The second one is not because it includes a column from the previous query, which is not from the same table.
The first query:

```
function1($id) {
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE id2 = $id";

    return($this->db->query($sql));
}
```

The second query:

```
function2() {
    $this->db->select('id2');
    $this->db->from('table2');
    $this->db->where('col1', '1');
    $this->db->limit($random_number, 1);

    return($this->db->get());
}
```

The calling function:

```
function() {
    $rs1 = function($id)->result_array(); // runs ok.
    $rs2 = function2()->result_array();   // error.
}
```

The error message:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'

SELECT `id`, `id2` FROM (`table2`) WHERE `col1` = '1' LIMIT 1, 30
```

The column `id` is not even in the second query, but it's included in the result.  How do I solve this problem?  Thank you.

Comment: by looking into your code everything looks fine but i suggest to post the complete model code so it would be more clear...

Comment: Is there somewhere in the code `$this->db->select('id1');`? Not only in these two functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

`$this->db->flush_cache()` before `$this->db->select('id2')`

Comment: You have to be selecting 'id' somewhere else too, because there's no reason for `id` to show.

Comment: It cannot be mixed up because function1() comes from one Model class, and function2() comes from another, so in function2(), I know for sure that I'm only selecting id2.  I really don't know what goes wrong here.

Comment: You're $this->db model is singular and can be accessed by any model. Meaning, two models can affect the same database call.